# Melhorando código jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Tenho um código em jquery que faz o seguinte, ele cria uma classe após o hover, até ai tá funcionando normalmente, mas como vou ter que replicar essa ação em outros lugares mas vai mudar as propriedades css de cada section, no caso são quatro, só que não queria ter que ficar replicando o mesmo código varias vezes, alguém sabe uma maneira de melhorar esse código para não ficar repetitivo ?

```
$('.bg_hover').hover(
function(){
    $(this).addClass('ativo');
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ativo');
}
);

$('.bg_hover_dois').hover(
function(){
    $(this).addClass('ativo_dois');
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ativo_dois');
}
);
```

Comment: Tens controlo sobre o HTML? precisas mesmo de ter classes diferentes? Porque não ter a mesma classe para todos? E essa classe `ativo` faz o quê? não podes fazer tudo sem jQuery? (ou seja: só com CSS)

Comment: Pena aceitares uma resposta antes de esclarecer dúvidas que coloquei aqui. Na próxima vez sugiro esclarecer melhor o problema, vais aprender mais e a pergunta irá ser mais útil a outros que tenham o mesmo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiciona um ID único a cada um dos seus elementos, e nessa função você pega esse id e adiciona a classe e remove a mesma, conforme o ID dele.

E todos os elementos que você quer q tenham esse comportamento precisam ter a classe `bg_hover`, apenas `bg_hover`

```
$('.bg_hover').hover(
function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).addClass('ativo'+ id);
},
function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).removeClass('ativo' + id);
}
);
```

Assim não precisa ficar replicando, somente alterar o id de cada elemento que você quer que tenha esse comportamento

Comment: Valeu, era isso que eu queria

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma `função` que receba como parâmetro:

1- O `elemento` a ser modificado.

2 - A classe do `elemento`.

Ficaria assim:

```js
function ModificaElemento(element, classe) {
  $(element).hover(
    function(){
        $(element).addClass(classe);
    },
    function(){
        $(element).removeClass(classe);
    }
  );
}

ModificaElemento(".bg_hover", 'ativo');
ModificaElemento(".bg_hover_dois", 'ativo');
```

```css
.ativo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg_hover"> Ativo  </div> <br>
<div class="bg_hover_dois"> Ativo 2 </div>
```

A chamada da função:  `ModificaElemento(elemento, classe)`

Comment: Caro downvote, se puder explicar o que está errado eu ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score -1):

Você não precisaria de Javascript pra isso, consegue resolver apenas com HTML e CSS:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="active">meu link</a>
<a href="#" class="active2">meu link 2</a>
```

CSS

```
.active:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active2:hover {
    color: yellow
}
```

---

Mas caso você precise ou queira usar Javascript e jQuery pode utilizar o `toggleClass` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-class="active" class="link-hover">meu link</a>
<a href="#" data-class="active2" class="link-hover">meu link 2</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".link-hover").hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

CSS

```
.active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active2 {
    color: yellow
}
```

Ai as classes você pode montar como precisar, e é só mudar o atributo `data-class`